# How does "LiPP" work?

Tags: apk

Every single tweet right now seems to be about "Lipp":

[image]

It says "LiPP is the app to dub your voice over the videos you like! Become your favourite character!"

I'm interested to know how this app works - does it have it's own built in audio / video encoder, or is the video uploaded and downloaded to a server (using data / WiFi), or does it use another app that already exists as part of Android and has an API for this?

Comment: Could you provide the real objective? Why would you want to know the functioning of this app? My point is, this site serves end-users, so please explain how your question is relevant to an end-user. I'm beginning to see this question asked from the perspective of development, but that's just me.

Comment: @Firelord Well the main "end user" perspective would be wether it needs WiFi/ data.

Comment: If you're talking about the [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bobler.lipp), to put it simply, yes, the app needs WiFi/data (can be seen on the list of permissions). However, I haven't tried this app, so I can't tell how far does this app needs internet connection (will experiment if there's time)